# Dialogflow fulfillments timeout after 5 seconds, How can we overcome this limit?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Imagine the following scenario:

1. Our client starts a conversation with our bot regarding a problem with one of their websites.
2. We go and check the website in our backend through our fulfilment web service and if there is no obvious problem we want to then generate a screenshot of the website and present it to our client.
3. The screenshot could take more than 5 seconds to take as many websites take longer than 5 seconds to fully load.
4. As a result the response timeouts.
5. We can't force our clients to redesign their websites to lead faster than 5 seconds just so that our chatbot can handle their request.

I assume there are many other real-world examples in which fulfillments can take more than 5 seconds.

Example:

```
Client: My website www.example.com doesn't load.
Bot: I just checked the website and it loads fine for me. Here is a screenshot of your website for you to check:
{Image goes here}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is - you can't.

There are some tricks that work sometimes, but they won't work in all scenarios, and aren't good practices anyway.

Your best bet would be to respond to the user with a message saying you're doing some checks and diagnostics and to ask for an update in a moment (and, if possible, provide a Suggestion Chip prompting them to ask for it). After sending that message, launch a background task to do the checks to see what might be going on and take the screen shot. When they ask for an update, you can report with what you have (latency time, the screen shot, etc) or if things are being slow and that you're still checking.